# GetSystemInfo doesn't work

Tags: c++, system

I'm trying to determine if the current system is 32 or 64 bit. And I want to get that info from the SystemInfo, but it VS gives me error's when I try to compile this. I can't use most other methods to determine if the OS is 64 or 32 bit. Because I need to check if windows is 64 bit and not the process.

```
LPSYSTEM_INFO info;
GetSystemInfo(&info); // Error
```

IntelliSense: argument of type "LPSYSTEM_INFO *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSYSTEM_INFO"

error C2664: 'GetSystemInfo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPSYSTEM_INFO *' to 'LPSYSTEM_INFO'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `info` buffer should be of type `SYSTEM_INFO`, not `LPSYSTEM_INFO`. When you capture its address with `&info` you'll get the `LPSYSTEM_INFO` pointer you need to pass into `GetSystemInfo`.

(In case it's not clear `LPSYSTEM_INFO` is a typedef, aliased to `SYSTEM_INFO *`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
SYSTEM_INFO info;
GetSystemInfo(&info);
```